# Unable to use google-cloud-storage in Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am not able to use `google-cloud-storage` in my Airflow.
I am using cloud composer for my Airflow environment.

Dag is not accepting it when I am using the below statement in my **.py** code

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

Its giving me an error saying that `invalid character in identifier (MyPythonCode.py, line 6(where I am using that statement)`

I have installed the required pypi package (google-cloud-storage) in my cloud composer PYPI Packages.

Whenever I am commenting that line, my DAG accepts .py file.

 I have seen the same issue raised by other person [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261750/cannot-deploy-dags-on-google-composer-if-i-import-google-cloud-storage/52539581#comment93786008_52539581), but when he added the required package, it started working. But not in my case.

Comment: Did you install it using the instructions in https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies ??

Comment: It is possible you have invalid whitespace on that line. Hard to tell without seeing more. What version of Cloud Composer, Airflow, and Python?

Comment: Did you copy paste the line? Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14844830/435089) and see if it helps